# Freeform: sending Composer form submission notification to a dynamic email address

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a Contact Us form that is being generated in Composer and being assigned to my template via the Freeform Fieldtype. The template code simply uses the custom_field name:

i.e. {modal_form}

The form has a select statement that allows the user to select a location. Depending on the user's selection I would like that location to be notified via email of the form submission. Currently the site administrator has to manually forward the email to the correct location.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a Dynamic Recipients field on Composer?

It allows you to set a select drop-down which impacts the recipients of the email.